# Bouncing Ball Animation 2/3

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to make a ball animation where each bounce after the first one is reduced to 2/3 in terms of bounce height.

I tried changing the ySpeed variable, but that only reduced how fast the drop was. I also tried changing the y variable, but they did not output what I was expecting. There is also an issue with the ball flickering.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BallFrame extends Frame {
    private int x = 10;
    private int y = 100;
    private int xSpeed = 1;
    private int ySpeed = 10;
    private static final int BALL_SIZE = 30;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public BallFrame() {
        setTitle("Bounce Bounce");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Button start = new Button("Start");
        Button stop = new Button("Stop");
        Button cont = new Button("Continue");
        Button reset = new Button("Reset");
        start.addActionListener(e -> startAnimation());
        stop.addActionListener(e -> stopAnimation());
        cont.addActionListener(e -> contAnimation());
        reset.addActionListener(e -> resetAnimation());
        add(start);
        add(stop);
        add(cont);
        add(reset);
        setVisible(true);

        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    private void startAnimation() {
        isRunning = true;
        Thread animationThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (isRunning) {
                update();
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        animationThread.start();
    }

    private void stopAnimation() {
    }

    private void contAnimation() {
    }

    private void resetAnimation() {
    }

    private void update() {
        x += xSpeed;
        y += ySpeed;

        if (y > getHeight() - BALL_SIZE) {
            y = getHeight() - BALL_SIZE;
            ySpeed = -ySpeed - (ySpeed * (2 / 3));

        }

        if (x > getWidth() - BALL_SIZE) {
            x = getWidth() - BALL_SIZE;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics Ball) {
        Ball.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        Ball.fillOval(x, y, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) *if (y > getHeight() - BALL_SIZE) {* - you continually test against the height of the frame/panel. Instead you need a variable that is initialized to the height of the frame/panel. Then each time the ball hits the ground you would reduce this height by your desired factor. 2) Why are you using AWT? You should at least be using Swing which is less dated than AWT. You should then be using a Swing Timer for the animation, not a Thread.